# Error :- org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-annotations

```
I have Class Customer ,User , Customer has property manager of user class 

Class Customer {

/** The manager. */
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER")
    @JsonSerialize(using = EntitySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
    private User manager;
}
-------------------------------------
Class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = User.TABLE_NAME + "_SEQUENCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = User.TABLE_NAME + "_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = User.TABLE_NAME + "_SEQ")
    @Column(name = FIELD_ID, nullable = false)
    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.ShortVariable")
    private Integer id;

@Override
public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

@Override
    public void setId(final Integer newId) {
        //System.out.println("setID");
        id = newId;
    }
}
```

Now when i am trying to create criteria

final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("manager", "%"+searchTerm+"%"))

It throwing Error :-
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.User.id

Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.User.id to java.lang.String

**Id field is integer **

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the following:

```
final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class); criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("manager", "%"+searchTerm+"%"))
```

by the following:

```
final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class); criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("manager.name", "%"+searchTerm+"%"))
```

LIKE clause is applicable to text column only.

Comment: But as per situation i need to filter my condition wrt to id ...i.e manger.id. Any way to archive that

Answer (score 0):

this code to used

```
return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                          .createCriteria(UserTraining.class) 
                          .add(Restrictions.eq("userProfile.userId", userId))  
                          .list();
```

Answer (score -1):

You used this annotation to error remove

```
@Table(name="user_training")
@Entity
public class UserTraining {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    //Generate getter setter of id
/*
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int userId;

    */


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserProfile userProfile;


    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }


    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "training_id")
    private Training training;

    @Column(name="view_count")
    private int viewCount;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Training getTraining() {
        return training;
    }

    public void setTraining(Training training) {
        this.training = training;
    }

    public int getViewCount() {
        return viewCount;
    }

    public void setViewCount(int viewCount) {
        this.viewCount = viewCount;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does it help?

Comment: my this error remove to below anotation @JsonIgnore
 @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})